# O365 - E5 Developer Program - Microsoft Graph query service not available

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, onedrive, microsoft-graph-files

I am trying to set up the E5 program and start doing some integration with my app. One feature of my application is it should be able to upload files to a Teams channel in Teams. While I was able to grant permissions on the development account to create teams, channels and retrieve information. I could not figure out how to enable Microsoft Graph to query the drive.

For instance,

I am trying to call this API

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/{my group id}/drive
```

and, I always get the error "serviceNotAvailable".

I tried contacting Microsoft support and they said I have a developer account and they can't provide support to me, sad. Does anyone know if there are special permission I need to set up in azure portal or anywhere to enable the Drive APIs?

Comment: serviceNotAvailable means the service is not available. Try the request again after a delay. There may be a Retry-After header. How is it now?

Comment: @AllenWu yes, I tried multiple time within the day and also tried in this morning, I am still getting that message.

Comment: Are you able to access this Drive from Teams or SharePoint?

Comment: Yes, as a regular user, I can go to teams.microsoft.com and I can see the drives. Also, using the query navigator with the global admin, I can ping the url, but using the application credentials I cant get it working.